# Modify the "Add Colleague" panel (QuickLinkDialogForm.aspx) in Sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to write a code that does something different after the user push the "ok" button in the Add Colleague panel in Sharepoint 2010. For that, I've created my own page and copy the content and references of the original QuickLinksDialogForm.aspx. I've modified the calling methods so when the user clicks in "Add Colleage", my panel is open instead of the original one.

The problem I'm getting here is I'm not getting the original behaviour of the OOB panel. This is the original panel:

[image: Original]

And this is what I obtain:

[image: Custom]

So the first thig I thought was that I should have missed some controllers but this is the original aspx page header:

```
 <%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/dialog.master"      Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.QuickLinksDialogPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVUPWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="SEARCHWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

And this is my custom aspx header:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="quicklinksdialogform.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="CustomMySite.Layouts.CustomMySite.ApplicationPage,CustomMySite,Version=1.0.0.0,
 Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=8ac4e08d3c1be6b0" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/dialog.master"
 DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"%>
 <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="OSRVUPWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="SPSWC" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="SEARCHWC" Namespace="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
 <%@ Register Tagprefix="PublishingWebControls" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

There is something else I should take care of? Am I missing something obvious? Any help will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

The page needs a query string too, to know which user is it doing what.

Will show you the colleagues picker:

```
quicklinksdialogform.aspx?Mode=Person
```

Will show the colleague:

```
quicklinksdialogform.aspx?Mode=Person&NTName=domain\account
```